# How do i capture child prcess stderr data in parent process?

Tags: node.js

I want to capture the data written to stderr of child process in parent.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const child = cluster.fork();
    cluster.workers[child.id].process.stderr.on('data',(data)=>{console.log(data});
  }
  else {
    console.error("Child data");
  }
```

I tried to add a callback to the child process stderr in master. But stderr is null in the parent.
How can I capture "Child data"(stderr of child process) in parent?
The requirement is to use cluster node module and capture console.error. I can not use process.send to send data to parent.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this with a `Promise` so I `promisify` the `exec` command like this:

```js
const util = require("util");
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

let runCommand = async (cmd) => {
  const result = await exec(cmd)
  if (result.stdout) console.log("StdOut:",result.stdout)
  if (result.stderr) console.log("StdErr:",result.stderr)
  return result
}

runCommand("some command")
  .then( result => console.log("Finished successfully),
         reason => console.log("Failed with",reason.code"))
```

If an error is returned (non-zero) then the promise will not resolve and you can handle the rejection also.